# Complexity Theory -- NP- hard that are not NP

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity

I'm studying for the first time Complexity Theory and there is something i didnt understood about NP-hard problems:

why some problems in NP-Hard are actually not themselves in NP ?
And what the meaning of this ?
Can you show me ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857342/5647260

Comment: At the link in @AndrewLi's comment, look at the example in the section headed "NP hard". The point is that this problem is undecidable by any algorithm. In contrast, any NP problem would be solvable in exponential time by a brute-force search.